# How to identify 'sub' dataframes in a dataframe based on a specific column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a small sales pipeline dashboard in python and have the following issue:

I import data regarding the status of opportunities on a frequent basis looking like this:

```
        ID  Prospect_ID Client_name Date_stage  Stage_ID    Stage_name  Status  Probability Deal_size   Weighted_Revenue
    0   1   20001       ABC         5-6-2019    1           Suspect     Open    0,30        1800        540
    1   1   20001       ABC         15-7-2020   2           Prospect    Open    0,50        1800        900
    2   1   20001       ABC         20-8-2020   3           Proposal    Open    0,70        1800        1260
    3   1   20001       ABC         26-9-2020   4           Won         Won     1,00        1800        1800    
    4   2   20002       XYZ         5-6-2020    1           Suspect     Open    0,30        2400        720
    5   2   20002       XYZ         15-7-2020   2           Prospect    Open    0,50        2400        1200
    6   2   20002       XYZ         20-7-2020   3           Proposal    Open    0,70        2400        1680
    7   2   20002       XYZ         26-8-2020   5           Lost        Lost    1,00        2400        2400
    8   3   20003       KLM         3-6-2020    1           Suspect     Open    0,30        1800        540  
    9   4   20004       DEF         6-6-2020    1           Suspect     Open    0,30        7200        2160
    10  5   20005       PQR         7-6-2020    1           Suspect     Open    0,30        1800        540
    11  5   20005       PQR         7-7-2020    2           Prospect    Open    0,50        1800        900
    12  5   20005       PQR         31-8-2020   3           Proposal    Open    0,70        1800        1260
    13  6   20006       MNO         10-7-2020   1           Suspect     Open    0,30        18000       5400
    14  6   20006       MNO         13-9-2020   2           Prospect    Open    0,30        9600        2880 
    15  7   20007       STV         18-6-2020   1           Suspect     Open    0,30        5400        1620
    16  7   20007       STV         21-8-2020   2           Prospect    Open    0,50        5400        2700
```

The first two opportunities (ID 1 and 2) are completed, one resulting in a deal, the other in a loss.  The other 5 opportunities are still pending. Hopefully they get into the following stage due to actions taken by the sales people. And as said, this list is updated frequently, representing these actions.

In the meantime I want to do analysis on this data. I would like to know what the average duration of the several stages is, eg. how long it takes to get from 'suspect' to 'propect'. Or the total duration of the sales cycles, so from 'suspect' to 'won' (which is the cumulation of the first). But I need to do that per prospect. So, I would like to add a column that gets the days between row 0 and row 1 (15-7-2020 minus 5-6-2020 = 40 days). But not between row 3 and 4, because these are different prospects. And if the sales cycle is not yet completed (status = open), I want to use today as the date. Also, in the next run, prospect 3 might have gone to stage 'prospect'. This will add a new row. And the same could be happening with all other prospects where the sales cycles has not finished yet.

For all these things I need to know who is the prospect and in which stage the sales process is or where this prospect ends (if Status is either Won or Lost). So, the actual questions is: How can I group row 0-3, 4-7, 8, 9, 10-12, etc. and identify in which stage the process is?

Do I need to make a dict, based in the unique values of column Prospect_ID and loop over the 5 possible stages? Or is there another way. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: there are  several questions rolled into this.  Please edit this to *one* well-defined question (ok to create several questions).  This will increase the chance of someone answering

Comment: Thanks, edited it somewhat. The real question is in the last two paragraphs. I do know how to add a column, calculate the cumulative, etc.